# Why HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsync doesn't throw an exception when the response is HTML instead of JSON?

Tags: json, exception, blazor, httpclient

I'm learning Blazor.
I have created a Blazor WASM App with the "ASP.NET Core Hosted" option.
So I have 3 projects in the solution: Client, Server and Shared.

The following code is in the Client project and works perfectly when the endpoint is correct (obviously). But at some point I made a mistake and messed up the request URI, and then I noticed that the API returned an HTML page with code 200 OK (as you can see in the Postman screenshot below the code).

I expected one of my try-catches to get this, but the debugger jumps to the last line (return null) without throwing an exception.

My first question is why?

My second question is how can I catch this?

I know fixing the endpoint fixes everything, but would be nice to have a catch that alerts me when I have mistyped an URI.

Thanks.

```
private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
public async Task<List<Collaborator>> GetCollaborators()
{
    string requestUri = "api/non-existent-endpoint";
    try
    {
        var response = await _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<CollaboratorsResponse>(requestUri);
        if (response == null) 
        {
            // It never enters here. Jumps to the last line of code.
        }
        return response.Collaborators;
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("An error occurred.");
    }
    catch (NotSupportedException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The content type is not supported.");
    }
    catch (JsonException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid JSON.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    return null;
}
```

[image: Postman Screenshot]

Comment: What non-existing-endpoint has to do with GetCollaborators? Call GetCollaborators in postman

Comment: That's my attempt to throw an exception.

Comment: It doesn't give any exception

Comment: Exactly. That's my question.

Comment: If you receive null it could be Collaborators=null  Is Collaborators html? but it doesn't matter if it is null

Comment: It jumps to the last line. No matter what I do. I already tried checking for nulls. Doesn't work. I updated the example to show this. Thanks.

Comment: No repro. It _does_ throw a JSonException.

Answer (score 3):

It is never a good idea to use GetFromJsonAsync. You are not the first who is asking about the strange behavior. Try to use GetAsync. Then at least you will know, what is going on.

```
var response = await client.GetAsync(requestUri);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var stringData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CollaboratorsResponse>(stringData);
    ... your code
} 
else
{
    var statusCode = response.StatusCode.ToString(); // HERE is your error status code, when you have an error
}
```

Comment: I am trying to use it because of this article:
https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/sending-and-receiving-json-using-httpclient-with-system-net-http-json

Comment: Thanks for the code but my question is why GetFromJsonAsync doesn't throw an exception. I am aware there are other alternatives. My objective is to understand how GetFromJsonAsync works, and how it behaves. Thanks again.

Comment: @CesarDaniel This is what I am advising your.  Use another syntax and you will know what is the problem

Comment: https://github.com/hassanhabib/RESTFulSense